# How can a char array of hex values be sent as plain text over serial

Tags: c, hex, ascii, stm32

I am using an STM32, and monitoring the serial port using CoolTerm.

I have an array, that stores the following: 0x01 0xFA 0xAA 0x05 ... etc.
I want to sent that over serial and see those values in plain text.

**When I use the following:**

```
char array[10] = { 0x01, 0xFA, 0xAA, 0x05, 0x01, 0xFA, 0xAA, 0x05, 0x01, 0x01 };
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, (uint8_t *)array, len, 1);
```

**The output on CoolTerm is:**

*. . . . . . . . . .*

Dots instead of plain text values are shown, if I switch to HEX mode I can see the values.

**What I need the output to look like:**

*"0x01 0xFA 0xAA 0x05 0x01 0xFA 0xAA 0x05 0x01 0x01"*

I imagine this is due to the array storing byte literals, but I have no idea what to use to see the hex in plain text in the ASCII decoding serial monitor.

Comment: @KamilCuk I need all of my output to show in ASCII mode, I don't want to bounce between plain text and hex just to see the values of the array.

Comment: Re "*What I need the output to look like:*", I highly highly doubt that. But if so, you're asking how to convert numbers to their hex representation, which you can easily look up.

Comment: Is the serial link for debug only or used to transmit data to some other device?

Comment: @Matthieu It's a debug monitor so it just sends data on a serial port.

Comment: You can do something like this using `sprintf()` and specify the format to be %x for hex.

uint8_t temperature_C; //contains the computed temperature
char buffer[16];
temperature_C = ComputeTemperature((uint8_t)ADC1->DR);  
sprintf(buffer, "%d", temperature_C);  
UART_Send_String((uint8_t*)buffer, sizeof(buffer));

Comment: Re "*No that isn't remotely the question.*", Then why did you accept the answer that shows how to do exactly that?

Comment: Yes it is. That is exactly what it is doing. For example, you stored the number one (as produced by the number literal `0x01`) in `array[0]`. The code takes that number and converts it to a string that is the hex representation of that number (`0x01`)

Comment: [Docs for %x](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf): "converts an unsigned integer into hexadecimal representation hhhh."

Comment: I concede. I didn't fundamentally understand what you wrote. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use `sprintf()` to a `char*` then send it. Something like:

```
char* buf = malloc(5*len);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    sprintf(buf+5*i, "0x%02x ", array[i]);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, buf, 5*len-1, 1);
free(buf);
```

You need to allocate five time the amount of bytes because a single byte will transform into 5:

`0` `x` `?` `?` `<space>`

then you don't transmit the last space over the serial link (hence the `-1` in `5*len-1`).

You can also add an `\n` at the end instead of the last space, and then transmit it:

```
...
buf[5*len-1] = '\n';
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, buf, 5*len, 1);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: @NoOne my pleasure :)